# Shell script example to stop execution of all processes with a certain UID?

Tags: shell, scripting, uid

I can't seem to find any examples on the internet for this particular task.

Comment: Try `for i in $(pgrep -U $UID); do kill -9 $i; done` or `pkill -U $UID` whichever seems suitable, replace $UID with the required UID or just assign it a value beforehand.

Comment: All solutions will require CAP_KILL (permission to kill any process), or to be root (root has this permission).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this either via:

```
for i in $(pgrep -U $UID_OF_ANOTHER_USER); do kill -9 $i; done
```

OR

```
pkill -U $UID_OF_ANOTHER_USER
```

You can use the first one to do something more other than just killing those processes, like listing all of them while killing.

Comment: As $UID is the user id of the current user. This will kill your own processes. In addition, it may kill itself before finishing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution, that will work if you are root.

`su $uid -c kill SIGSTOP -1`

Explanation: become that user, and kill everything that you can.

---

All solutions will require CAP_KILL (permission to kill any process), or to be traditional root (root has this permission), and permission (capability to change its own uid), as used by this solution.

Note I sent sigstop, this will pause the process (as asked for ☺). Chose the signal that you want. Use sigkill as last resort.

Answer (score 0):

```
killall -u $user -STOP
```

This is safe if run as another user and (for other signals) if no parent process belongs to the affected user.

ctrl-alt-delor's solution is probably better (safer). This one has the advantage of giving you a real exit code, though. The other one probably does not as both `su` and `kill` get killed themselves.